# sidekiq sending class as args gives stacklevel too deep error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, sidekiq

After setting up [sidekiq](http://mperham.github.com/sidekiq/), I observed a strange behavior with respect to the arguments passed to the `Sidekiq::Client.push` method

If I give `self.class` as args, then I either get a `SystemStackError (stack level too deep)` OR the server simply hung up, thereafter accepting no request.

`Sidekiq::Client.enqueue(ActivityWorker, self.id, self.class)`

```
SystemStackError (stack level too deep):
  actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:70


  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@restro/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (2.0ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@restro/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (2.0ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@restro/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (37.8ms)
```

But if I give `self.class.name` then it works without any flaw.
`Sidekiq::Client.enqueue(ActivityWorker, self.id, self.class.name)`

I found that the args are serialized before they are passed to the worker, but am unable to figure out this scenario.

Here's my Worker class

```
class ActivityWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options queue: 'high', retry: false

  def perform(res_id, res_class)
    # do some activity
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't enqueue job with arguments like class object. It should be simple types, for example strings, numbers, hashes and arrays of them.

For the most of classes, except the spedical ones which I mentioned and probably some other, Sidekiq serialize this parameter to redis just as empty hash. So it's no way to deserialize from it back to your class.

I suggest you to pass `self.class.name` to the `enqueue` method as you tried, and then use `constantize` to get a class from string.